# Best test to ranks three groups of a continuous variable

Tags: r, bootstrap, ranking

I have derived intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) values to determine interobserver agreement between three judges, using three separate methods.
Using method A, I am getting ICC 0.918, method B gives me 0.78, and method C gives me 0.847. I want to know if the ICC from method A is indeed higher statistically than the other two. I am using bootstrap resampling to obtain a range of resampled ICC values with corresponding medians and 95% confidence intervals. But would like to know what would be the test to rank the winner among the three scores. I only need to know the winner vs. (two) losers, not an exact ranking.
I will provide more information/datasets if needed but i hope this is sufficient